# how to return the iterations over keys as a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to return a string that contains the values of 2 attributes of every object in a dictionary and it's key . Every line is a key and the 2 attributes of it's object. The problem is that since the return statement ends the function, i only get the first key. I can get the results with print but i need the function to return the result.This is my attempted function:

```
    aemptystring = ""
    for key in self.cases.keys():
        a = key, self.cases[key].color, self.cases[key].thetype
        b = str(a) + "\n"
        result = aemptystring + b
        return result
```

and its gives me this:

```
"((3, 0), 'blanc', 'pion')\n"
```

It only does it for 1 key .The dictionary cases has number tuples as a key like (3,0) and the attributes of its object are  .color which can be "noir" or "blanc" and .thetype is "pion" or "dame"

if i use `print(aemptystring + b)`i get the iterations for each key like i want which is like this:

```
((3, 0), 'blanc', 'pion')

((5, 4), 'blanc', 'pion')

((2, 1), 'noir', 'pion')

((1, 6), 'noir', 'pion')

....etc
```

How can i get the function to return the result of the iterations like the print gives me?
I can't just use print because i need to use the return of this function later on.The return also needs to be a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `return` inside the loop.  :)

You almost got there with the `aemptystring`.  You just have to keep adding onto it.

```
result = ""
for key in self.cases.keys():
    a = key, self.cases[key].color, self.cases[key].thetype
    b = str(a) + "\n"
    result = result + b
return result
```

But concatenating strings repeatedly is quadratic, so it's better to build a list and then join it.

```
lines = []
for key in self.cases.keys():
    a = key, self.cases[key].color, self.cases[key].thetype
    lines.append(str(a) + "\n")
return ''.join(lines)
```

And you can make this a bit shorter with `.items()` and some string formatting.

```
lines = []
for key, case in self.cases.items():
    a = key, case.color, case.thetype
    lines.append("{0!r}\n".format(a))
return ''.join(lines)
```

It's a little weird to return a big string of Python `repr`s like this, though.  Curious: what is this string used for?

Comment: Hi, the first code is what i want but the "\n" doesn't make a line end like in my exemple with the print in the OP and just gets printed like this "((3, 0), 'blanc', 'pion')\n((5, 4), 'blanc', 'pion')\n....etc" Do you have a solution for this?Also the string is used to save the information in a file later on in another function. thanks

Comment: if it's printed with literal quotes then you're printing a `repr`.  are you calling `repr`, or putting it in a list or tuple somewhere?  what does the calling code do with this string?

Comment: actually i think it's fine . the plan is to call it in another function to write the string it output in a text file.i got confused because when i called it in idle it showed it like in my last comment but it shows it the way i want it in the text file with every key and it's object attributes in one line e.g. ((3, 0), 'blanc', 'pion') in one line ,((5, 4), 'blanc', 'pion') in another and so on.I don't know if "\n" not ending line in idle is normal but it works the way i want. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You could either append the results to a list and return the list of results outside the for loop, or you could use something called a [generator](https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/) which allows your function to resume executing where it left off after returning a value.

```
def generate_stuff():

    for key in self.cases.keys():
        a = key, self.cases[key].color, self.cases[key].thetype
        yield str(a) + "\n"

for result in generate_stuff():
    print result
```